# prepopulated_fields is not working after installing django-grappelli

Tags: python, django

as the title, I want to make my Slug field is auto filled, the native theme of admin Django works perfectly, but after installing django-grappelli, it does not work anymore.

```
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['posted']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}
    list_display = ['title','category', 'posted']

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}

admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

*It does not show any error

Comment: Open browser console and post if any error/exceptions found there.

Comment: @moonstruck it does not show any error

Comment: Post your settings.py.